# How do I read all jsons in a dir, store the contents and compare the result

Tags: json, node.js, bots, discord

How do I accomplish it? It needs to read all the json files in one Directory, remember the contents and then compare it with a variable in nodejs.

e.g. There are three json files, the contents are stored and checked to see if any of the contents equals to "hi". If so, execute something, else, execute something else.

I've spent hours trying to Google something like this to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code which do the following :

- List a directory
- Read each file of the directory and store content
- Filter file matching a specified target content
- Apply an action on each matching item

  ```
  var fs      = require("fs");
  var async   = require("async");


  var folder = __dirname+"/yolo"
  var target = "hi";

  var myAction = function(file, content)
  {
      console.log("My action");
      console.log(file);
      console.log(content);
  };

  fs.readdir(folder, function(err, item){

  if(err)
  {
      // do stg
      console.log("error readdir");
      console.log(err);
      process.exit(0);
  }
  else
  {
      var content = [];

      async.eachOf(item, function(e, i, ecb){

          fs.readFile(folder+"/"+e, "utf8", function(err, data){

              if(err || !data)
              {
                  console.log("error readFile");
                  console.log(err);
                  return ecb(err || true);
              }
              else
              {
                  content.push({
                      file:e,
                      text: data.toString()
                  });
                  return ecb(null);
              }
          })
      }, function(err){
          if(err)
          {
              // do stg
              console.log("error eachOf");
              console.log(err);
              process.exit(0);
          }
          else
          {
              // get only item matching the string
              var filters = content.filter(function(e){return e.text == target});

              // call actions on each matching item
              filters.forEach(function(e){
                  myAction(e.file, e.text);
              });

              process.exit(1);
          }
      });
  }
  });
  ```